# Redirect external subdirectory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, referrer

The following code works perfectly to redirect an external URL to a subdirectory on my site:

```
RewriteCond %{http_referer} abc\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ my-subdirectory/ [R=302,L]
```

This code tells anyone navigating from abc.com to my website to be redirected to the subdirectory listed (e.g. mywebsite.com/my-subdirectory).

But what I really want is to redirect a referring subdirectory.  in other words:  abc.com/some-subdirectory.  How do I add "some-subdirectory" to the first line of the above code to have abc.com/some-subdirectory reroute to mywebsite.com/my-subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{http_referer} abc\.com/some-subdirectory [NC]
```

Comment: This is the logical solution I think, and I tried that one as well.  But it also doesn't work.  The referring subdirectory will ignore that RewriteRule and land on the homepage.  Thanks for you time.  It is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this :

```
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /anotherdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

And look at [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-using-htaccess/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  that did not work for me though.  I added this rewrite rule to the middle of the existing code as follows: 'code'RewriteCond %{http_referer} abc\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*)$ /some-subdirectory/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^$ my-subdirectory/ [R=302,L]'code'

Comment: (apologies that I don't know how to format the code in my responses to you)

Comment: You're welcome , i've tried it and worked! So , just edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you again.  Which part of that line of code is supposed to contain my actually subdirectory folder name?  Also - I found that page you linked to but on that page they are always working within the same domain (mysample.com is their example).  In this case the external domain (the referrer) is different from my domain.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I suggest you read whole document . But if you want redirect `example.com/some-directory` to `yourdomain.com/sub-dicrectory` you should use this one in the abc.com htaacess file : `RewriteRule ^url-string-to-redirect$ http://www.yourdomain.com/your-new-url-string [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks again for your time.  The other answer worked for me so I didn't get a chance to try this.

Comment: I was voting up but I'm too new to do so.  Thanks again.